# Limit URLSession.sared.dataTasks to 10 downloads

Tags: swift, blogs, urlsession

I'm creating a blog reader and I want it to just show 10 entries and if the user wants more he must scroll to load more. Right now I'm using

```
              let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { 
                    (data, response, error) in

                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        self.createAlert(title: "Error", message: "Something Went Wrong")
                    } else {
                        if let urlContent = data {
                            do {
                                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                                print(jsonResult)
                                if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? NSArray {
                                    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
                                    let request = NSFetchRequest<Event>(entityName: "Event")
                                    do {
                                        let results = try context.fetch(request)
                                        if results.count > 0 {
                                            for result in results {
                                                context.delete(result)
                                                do {
                                                    try context.save()
                                                } catch {
                                                    print("Specific delete failed")
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch {
                                        print("Delete failed")
                                    }


                                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                                }

                            } catch {

                                print("JSON Processing Failed")

                            }

                        }

                    }


                }

                task.resume()
```

This lets me download the info for the blog but if there are many posts it takes ages for it app to load and show the info, so I want to show 10 by 10 or something like that. But I havne't found an option to limit the number of data I download, Is it possible to make it only download 10 posts, I've seen I can configure the time it gets to make the task, is it the only way to do it? Thanks

Comment: The best way to do this is to ask the blog to only give you limited data. If it can't do that, then you could simply throw away the data you don't want.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Didn't knew I could do this. Blogger allows me to do it and also download only the info I need